# Can we take backup of our current database through java programming?

Tags: java, database, backup

Can we take backup of our current database through java programming ?

Comment: As I said in the answer: specify the database. And tag properly: I can't see how this is related to JSP at all. It should probably be tagged with java, databases and whatever database you are trying to backup (mysql etc.)

Comment: You've tagged this as JSP, are you building some admin app to run from JSP?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified what type of database so I'll presume something SQL-ish and accessible over JDBC. If this is the case, [DBBackup](https://dbbackup.dev.java.net/) should do what you want. That said, you might want to use the database-native tool (for MySQL, that's mysqldump; for PostgreSQL, pg_dump) as it'll probably be quicker, more reliable and so on.